# Adding SSL to a NFC connection

Tags: android, ssl, nfc

I am writing an Android App that is using NFC tags in order to transfer some information. For the moment I have the read function which reads the content from the NFC tag:

```
protected NdefMessage[] getNdefMessages(Intent intent) {
    // Parse the intent
    NdefMessage[] msgs = null;
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
        || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = 
            intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        if (rawMsgs != null) {
            msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
            }
        } else {
            // Unknown tag type
            byte[] empty = new byte[] {};
            NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_UNKNOWN, empty, empty, empty);
            NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {
                record
            });
            msgs = new NdefMessage[] {
                msg
            };
        }
    } else {
        finish();
    }
    return msgs;
}
```

Now, I would like to add security to the communication, that is SSL. However, I really don't know what steps do I have to take in order to implement this functionality. 
Is there some NFCSecurity class or something like that, that does all the work for you?

Any idea?

Comment: A complete SSL/TLS stack is pretty complex especially because of the different protocols (SSL 2.0, SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2) and the dozens of cipher suites. I assume this is too much for a small NFC-chip. Anyway you would need to set-up a PKI for creating the SSL/TLS-NFC-server-certificates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android NFC API gives you access to both the (low-level) tag communication and the (high-level) NDEF message storage on a tag (or transferred via Android Beam).
Adding security to that, while still retaining the benefits of automatic NDEF message reading and writing, could be done by, for example, encrypting the payload of the `NdefRecord` you use.

SSL/TLS works on the connection level. There are no tags that support such a thing, as far as I am aware. You could consider adding SSL/TLS to NFC peer-to-peer communication, but that does currently not exist. It would involve modifying the Android NFC stack and building a custom Android system image (if it is possible at all). It is not something that can be added on top of Android Beam by an app.

Comment: According to a paper that explains all the aspects regarding the NFC security (http://ece.wpi.edu/~dchasaki/papers/Security%20in%20NFC.pdf), the best approach to enable security in this technology is to provide a standard secure channel. So I was hoping that there was an easier method to add SSL in order to solve the problem.
So, If I understood correctly, there's no way I could establish a secure layer between a tag and a device and the only way to secure the information is just by encrypting the data stored inside the tag... Is that correct?

Comment: The paper is actually about the NFC peer-to-peer protocol ISO 18902 as used by Android Beam, while NFC tag communication is based on ISO 14443 or JIS X6319-4 or ISO 15692. There are tags that support secure communication, for example MIFARE Classic (limited security nowadays), DESFire (using a proprietary command set) or a more advanced contactless smart card supporting Global Platform secure messaging.

Comment: Possible disadvantage of using such tags is that you will have to implement all communication with the tag in your app, your app will only work with such tags and the automatic discovery mechanism of Android to start the correct app will most likely not be supported.